# Contat 2 Lists from different tables into 1 and use AsQueryable()

Tags: linq, join, iqueryable

Attempting to return the below 2 lists into something I can then query against.

```
  var people = (from c in _context.FollowingPeople
      select new Models.Following.FollowingModel
      {
          Id = c.Id,
          MediaTypeId = c.MediaTypeId,
          Title = c.Title,
          ClientId = c.ClientId,
          Person = (from p in _context.SocialMediaPeople
          where p.Id == c.SocialMediaId
          select new Models.SocialMediaPeople
          {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Photo = p.Photo
          }).FirstOrDefault()
  });

  var generic = (from c in _context.FollowingGeneric
  select new Models.Following.FollowingModel
  {
      Id = c.Id,
      MediaTypeId = c.MediaTypeId,
      Title = c.Title,
      ClientId = c.ClientId,
      Person = null
  });

  var temp = people.Concat(generic).ToList();

  //var data = temp.AsQueryable();

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
  {
      data = data.Where(filter);
  }

  data = data.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId);

  return await data
                  .GetPaged(page, pageSize);
```

I have tried join, concat, even Zip but it results in various errors such as

> (Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.)

Comment: I believe your problem is that the named classes cannot be instantiated by the generated SQL. Try replacing them with anonymous classes by dropping the explicit class types: replace `new Models.Following.FollowingModel {...}` and `new Models.SocialMediaPeople {...}` with just `new {...}` to see how far you get.  If you still get an error, it might be that the environment cannot resolve the two different definitions of `Person = `. You might need to just include c.SocialMediaId (or null) in the results and perform the SocialMediaPeople lookup later. (You can remap the data later in the query.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got this working, the trick is to not perform any queries on the data until AFTER the concat.  Th below works...

```
var queryA =
    from c in _context.Set<FollowingPeople>()
    select new Models.Following.FollowingModel
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        MediaTypeId = c.MediaTypeId,
        Title = c.Title,
        ClientId = c.ClientId
    };
var queryB =
    from c in _context.Set<FollowingGeneric>()
    select new Models.Following.FollowingModel
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        MediaTypeId = c.MediaTypeId,
        Title = c.Title,
        ClientId = c.ClientId
    };

var queryC =
    from c in _context.Set<FollowingPublication>()
    select new Models.Following.FollowingModel
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        MediaTypeId = c.MediaTypeId,
        Title = c.Title,
        ClientId = c.ClientId
    };

var data = (from v in queryA.Union(queryB).Union(queryC)
select new Models.Following.FollowingModel
{
    Id = v.Id,
    MediaTypeId = v.MediaTypeId,
    Title = v.Title,
    ClientId = v.ClientId,
})
.AsNoTracking()
.AsQueryable();

 data = data.Where(x => x.ClientId == ClientId);

 return await data.GetPaged(page, pageSize);
```